# StaleObjectStateException i am getting on update a user account that was just created

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, locking

So i am dealing with the error:

> Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value
>   mapping was incorrect):
>   [Domain.Entities.General.Shipping#0]

when the user wants to update their shipping address in my application.

**Controller**

```
var shippingToAdd = new Shipping
                {
                    UserId = newUserId,
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName,
                    Address = model.ShippingStreet,
                    SteApt = model.ShippingAptSte,
                    City = model.ShippingCity,
                    State = model.ShippingState,
                    Zip = model.ShippingZip,
                    Country = shippingCountryId,
                };
                UserManagerService.UpdateShipping(shippingToAdd);
```

**UserManagerService**

```
public static ISession Context { get; set; }

        public UserManagerService(ISession context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

    public static int UpdateShipping(Shipping shipping )
    {
        using (ITransaction transaction = Context.BeginTransaction()) 
        {
            Context.Update(shipping);
            transaction.Commit();
            return 0; //Right Here is where StaleObjectStateException occurs
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway to lift the lock right before the Commit()? Or whats the best way to release a lock in general?

**STACK TRACE**

> [StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another
>   transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect):
>   [Domain.Entities.General.Shipping#0]]
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[]
>   includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj,
>   SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) +2548
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[]
>   includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj,
>   SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session) +533
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection,
>   Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId,
>   ISessionImplementor session) +2372
>   NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute() +975
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) +63
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) +165
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() +68
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource
>   session) +451
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent
>   event)
>
> +286    NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() +385    Service.Account.UserManagerService.UpdateShipping(Shipping shipping)
>   in
>   c:\Users\wd\Desktop\master\Service\Account\UserManagerService.cs:189
>   Controllers.PayPalController.PaymentWithCreditCard(CartViewModel
>   model, IEnumerable`1 cookiecart) in
>   c:\Users\wd\Desktop\master\Controllers\PayPalController.cs:552
>
>   Controllers.PayPalController.Continue(CartViewModel model) in
>   c:\Users\wd\Desktop\master\Controllers\PayPalController.cs:136
>
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +268
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +87
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +603
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +93
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   +97    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +53
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +137
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +187
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +136

Comment: You haven't provided enough information here. For example, what is `Context.Update(...)`?

Comment: sorry added it in my update.

Comment: Still not enough info, is this perhaps nHibernate? We are not psychic!

Comment: yeah nHibernate, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are calling Update() if you are trying to add a new object. Did you mean to use ISession.Save() or ISession.SaveOrUpdate()?

Comment: you are absolutely right.... i was passing a new instance into an update. that was the problem.